# iOS devices [non-jailbreak] anti-theft apps better than Find My iPhone

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

Is there a super anti-theft on App Store , which excludes apps from Cydia (a.k.a jail-break apps) that is better than Find My iPhone ?

This super anti-theft must do What Find My iPhone can and have the following when I turn on "Lost Mode" on this app:

- the theft has no ideas that he is being watched
- take photos using front/back camera every x minutes and send photos to my email
- disable iOS Devices turn off manually unless the devices are out of battery or are destroyed

Bonus: 1 time paid out rather than month-to-month subscription

Comment: What if this isn't possible without jailbreaking? Would you be OK with an answer that explains why?

Comment: @bmike, I'm open to your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps on the App Store must obey the App Store guidelines and stay within their sandbox.

> **2.5** Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
>   **2.6** Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Apps aren't able to disable an iOS device's power off functionality as this is fundamental to the device and is not able to be manipulated by an app on the device restricted to the code that is downloaded with the app:

> **2.8** Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

Furthermore, doing things such as taking photos in the background is not permitted per the App Store guidelines:

> **2.16** Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.

Therefore, such an app will not be found on the App Store.

Comment: I understand Apple Guideline to protect user's privacy. They should consider adding these anti-theft measurement to Find My Iphone app.

Comment: @MichaelNguyen-HaTaDu http://apple.com/feedback is one way to ask Apple to improve their services